# Which Activity start first

Tags: android, android-activity

In many android application the first activity can be either a login activity or the home activity (if the user is already logged in).

So the question is, which activity start at startup? Can be a good idea start always the login activty and in the onCreate test if the user is already logged in?  For example:

```
onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(isUserAlreadyLoggedIn())
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can check this condition on onResume() method...

Comment: ok, but the basic idea of launch always the login activty at startup, is good?

Comment: if user is already logged in then no need to start the login activity...

Comment: yes, but in the Manifest I can declare only one Activty that have to start at startup

Comment: ya.. actually ur main activity will start first and on call of onresume ur second activity will begin

Comment: I know that this works good. I was just looking for a more clean solution.

Comment: this is the only way I know so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The activity you declare in Manifest to be your main activity is not necessary the first activity that will start when your application will be created.

Lets assume you have two activities Menu and Login, and you set your Login activity to be your main in manifest.

In case the first time you lunch your application you will get to Login activity. But if the user hit the home button while in Menu activity, and than also kill your application process, ether by visiting other activities until there is not space for your Menu activity or by manual killing the process using Task Killer(Note that there is deference between closing the application from settings with Force Stop, as it also clears the activities stack and using Task killer as Advanced task killer on Android Market). In this case the next time the user lunch your application, the first activity will be the Main menu.

As for user experience it's best to show him the Login activity more than once, just remember his details after his first successful login.

Your code seems valid to me.